# WordPress Golbal Capitalization

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a capitalization problem in wordpress. Every new word, regardless of where on the site, is capitalized.

I tried the following codes in Customize -> Additional CSS

[see screenshot of the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAen4.png)

Neither code works, please, help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please share the code as text and not as a screenshot, please also share something where the issue is reproducible so we can test any solutions accurately

Comment: Somewhere, something has put a css rule like `text-transform: capitalize;` so it applies to all text. Your best bet for fixing this is to find where that css rule comes from and get rid of it. Try right-click Inspect on some offending text, then look at the css.